# sub domains in tornado web app for SAAS

Tags: python, webserver, subdomain, tornado, saas

I have a web app which runs at www.mywebsite.com.

I am asking user to register and enter a subdomain name for their login. e.g. if user enters subdomain as "demo", then his login url should be "www.demo.mywebsite.com".

How this can be done in tornado web app, as tornado itself is a web server.
Or serving the app with nginx or other web serving services is the only way ?

Thanks for you help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`self.request.host` under `tornado.web.RequestHandler` will contain subdomain so you can change application logic according to subdomain eg. load `current_user` based on cookie + subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Tornado itself does not handle subdomains.

You will need to something like NGNIX to control subdomain access.